# Jquery IE Compatibility : Member Not Found Error

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I have an aspx page. While i was developing that page, The error: 'member not found' occured in jquery 1.11.0 library. To avoid this error I used meta tag like shown below

```
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=10" />
                                  or
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
```

With that tag i avoided the error and i was able to finish my aspx page. After i finished my project I created an application on IIS and publish the project to that application. When I browse the web form from IIS, 
the error :'Member not found' occured again. Even though i use the other versions of jquery libraries the error didn't went away. What is changing when i try to reach the page from url.

The Part Of jquery library where error occured

```
// IE6/7 do not support getting/setting some attributes with get/setAttribute
if ( !getSetAttribute ) {

// Use this for any attribute in IE6/7
// This fixes almost every IE6/7 issue
nodeHook = {
    set: function( elem, value, name ) {
        // Set the existing or create a new attribute node
        var ret = elem.getAttributeNode( name );
        if ( !ret ) {
            elem.setAttributeNode(
                (ret = elem.ownerDocument.createAttribute( name ))
            );
        }

           ret.value = value += "";  **error occured here**


        // Break association with cloned elements by also using setAttribute (#9646)
        if ( name === "value" || value === elem.getAttribute( name ) ) {
            return value;
        }
    }
};
```

How can i solve this. Thanks for reply in advance

Comment: provide your code here..

Comment: The exact error message would also help -- which member is not found?

Comment: have you tried using jQuery 1.11.1? As far as I can remember, I had a similar issue and it went away by using 1.11.1

Answer (score 0):

The head tag was like

```
   <head runat="server">
```

After i remove 'runat' attribute, it worked properly.